# C# WinForms - How to (do something) with several textboxes between 2 values

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form, where a 'user' inputs values into several textboxes and if the values are between certain ranges I want it to do something.

Is it possible to check multiple textboxes simultaneously as opposed to having them checked like so:

```
if (int.Parse(textbox1.Text) >= 100 && int.Parse(textbox1.Text) <= 2000)
{
    mylist.Add(int.parse(textbox1.text));
}
if (int.Parse(textbox2.Text) >= 100 && int.Parse(textbox2.Text) <= 2000)
{
    mylist.Add(int.parse(textbox1.text));
}
if (int.Parse(textbox3.Text) >= 100 && int.Parse(textbox3.Text) <= 2000)
{
    mylist.Add(int.parse(textbox3.text));
}
```

Comment: In line 7, assuming you meant `int.Parse(textbox2.Text)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to put them in a list:

```
var textboxes = new List<TextBox>(new[] { textbox1, textbox2, textbox3 });
```

and then loop through this list and probably parse the value only once:

```
foreach (var t in textboxes) 
{
    int value = int.Parse(t.Text);
    if (value >= 100 && value <= 2000)
    {
        mylist.Add(value);
    }
}
```

or if you prefer using LINQ you could also do this one liner:

```
IList<int> mylist = textboxes
    .Select(t => int.Parse(t.Value))
    .Where(value => value >= 100 && value <= 2000)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract method:

```
public void AddValue(string text, List<int> list)
{
    var value = int.Parse(test);
    if (value >= 100 && value <= 2000)
    {
        list.Add(value);
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
var list = new List<int>();
AddValue(textbox1.Text, list);
AddValue(textbox2.Text, list);
AddValue(textbox3.Text, list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple boolean method that does this work on a textbox passed to it and tells the calling code if the parsing is successful

```
private bool ParseText(TextBox txt, List<int> theList)
{
    int value;
    if(Int32.TryParse(txt.Text, out value))
    {
        if(value >= 100 && value <= 2000)
        {
            theList.Add(value);
            return true;
        }
     }
    return false;
}
```

Now you could call this method

```
if(!ParseText(textBox1, mylist))
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid value in TextBox1");
if(!ParseText(textBox2, mylist))
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid value in TextBox2");
if(!ParseText(textBox3, mylist))
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid value in TextBox3");
```

Notice that a textbox whose text is expected to be an integer but is typed by the user should be always parsed using `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Parse` because Parse raises an exception if the text cannot be converted to an integer